# How to avoid denormalized numbers?

Tags: floating-point

The same floating-point AMD X86-64 digital signal processing system mentioned in my [previous question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/124/how-to-implement-a-digital-oscillator) has a problem where it sometimes slows down substantially when signals attain values very near (but not exactly) zero.

The problem is that [denormalized floating point values](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) require special processing by the CPU which is dramatically slower than dealing with normal floating point values.  This can cause the DSP system to run too slow--taking longer than $1/f_s$ to compute everything that needs to be computed in one cycle.

A workaround is to add a small offset to all numbers to force them into the range of normal numbers.  Is there a way to instead instruct the FPU to simply not generate denormal numbers in the first place?

The OS is Linux and the compiler is `gcc`.

EDIT: Also, what are the numerical consequences of disabling denormal numbers?

Comment: Are you using x87 FPU instructions, MMX, SSE, AVX, all of the above, etc.?

Comment: Just FPU, I think.  Double precision.  For the most part, the math is implemented directly in C and the C compiler (gcc) does whatever it does.  Instead of the math library we use some small inline assembly functions to get `sincos`, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can force denormal numbers to zero by setting the "flush to zero" and "denormals are zero" bits (15,6) in the [MXCSR](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2021-8/set-the-ftz-and-daz-flags.html) register.

```
_mm_setcsr( _mm_getcsr() | (1<<15) | (1<<6));
```

Comment: I think they have names for those bits, don't they, Mark?  I thought they're called **FTZ** and **DAZ**.  [Like here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2021-8/set-the-ftz-and-daz-flags.html).