# How should I modulate a $16$ bit input using FSK?

Tags: modulation, fsk

I need to graph a $16$ bits binary sequence, assuming that it'll be a FM analog signal I need to apply FSK to it.

So, I think I should use the formula

$A \cos(2\pi f_1 t)$ for binary $1$'s

$A \cos(2\pi f_2 t)$ for binary $0$'s

But I'm really confused about how to set a method for getting the graph for my $16$ bit sequence ...

Comment: Can you indicate what tool(s) you are using to simulate / graph your signals?

Comment: You need to consider/define you're bit duration.  Once this is defined, you can represent your binary sequence as a series of pulses with the desired bit duration.  You'll need to define the bit period to do the modualation as well.  Specifically how you code this depends on the tool(s) you are using.

Comment: I just want to try and write a software code where a user inputs any 16 bit binary sequence, I should validate it (lenght, only 0's and 1's) and graph it next.

Let's say, any user inputs 1010010011100011 next after validation for this input it will be charted

Comment: I consider that Amplitude will be reflected in the Y axis and Time in X axis, am I wrong?

Comment: The questions asked above are important and I don't think you've addressed them. Another important point: you may not want to just switch between two cosines at frequencies $f_1$ and $f_2$, as the equations you provided above suggest. That approach will yield a signal with discontinuous phase, which in many cases is undesirable. Instead, you could use an [NCO](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/124/how-to-implement-a-digital-oscillator/126#126) to implement a continuous-phase frequency-modulated signal.

Comment: It would probably help if you would explain why you want to modulate these 16-bit inputs.  The input is users typing in bits?  Okay.  After you modulate the data, what are you going to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the comments on the question and the OP's responses
don't seem to be converging, here goes.

- Pick a data rate $R$ bits/second (e.g. $10$ kilobits/second)
  that is acceptable to your client or boss.
  The FSK signal
  will then convey one bit every $R^{-1} = T$ seconds (every
  $T= 100$ microseconds if you chose the $R =10$ kbps data rate
  suggested as an example), and the $16$ bits that you need to
  transmit will be transmitted by an FSK signal $x(t)$ that will
  have a total duration $16T$ seconds ($1600$ microseconds for the
  example).  Specifically, let us assume that you need to define
  what $x(t)$ is for all $t$ in the interval $[0, 16T]$.
- Number the $16$ bits typed in by the user as $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{15}$
  where each $a_i$ can have value $0$ or $1$. Include in your
  program a snarky error message to be sent to the user if any of
  the $a_i$ have value other than $0$ or $1$
- Pick two positive integers $m_0$ and $m_1$. The FSK signal
  described below will use frequencies $m_0/T$ Hz and $m_1/T$ Hz.
  It is convenient, and possibly might even please your client or
  boss, if you choose *consecutive* integers as $m_0$ and $m_1$ such
  that the FSK signal fits in the frequency band allocated to the system.
- Define the signal $x(t)$ as follows.  For $i = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, 15$,
  $$x(t) = A \sin\left(2\pi\left[(1-a_i)m_0 + a_i m_1\left]\frac{t}{T}\right.\right.\right),~~~
  iT \leq t < (i+1)T.$$
  Several points need to be noticed with respect to this definition:

  - The quantity in square brackets has value $m_0$ if $a_i = 0$ and value $m_1$ if $a_i = 1$ and so during the time interval $[iT, (i+1)T)$, the signal
    consists of either $m_0$ periods or $m_1$ periods of a sinusoid. At the
    endpoints of the interval, the signal has value $0$. The signal thus has
    the *phase continuity* that is desirable in an FSK signal as noted
    by @JasonR in a comment.
  - If you are using some programming language to create an array of
    $16$ gazillion points that you will then pass to a graphics package to display
    as a graph of values of $x(t)$ as a function of $t$, then note that the
    formulas used to create the first gazillion points will differ from the
    formula used to create the next gazillion points etc.. The 
    formula needs to use $a_i$ to compute the values of the $i$-th
    subset of gazillion points. If you want
    to have a nice smooth graph of the sinusoids, it is necessary 
    to have $m_0$ and $m_1$ be onsiderably smaller than a gazillion
    so that you get plenty of points
    per period of each sinusoid.  Your graph will also have a *long*
    horizontal axis that will likely extend past one page even if printed in
    landscape mode on legal-size paper.