# What is the algorithm to generate sine waves of arbitrary frequency in the STFT domain?

Tags: fft, ifft, audio-processing, signal-synthesis

I'd like to write a DSP algorithm to do additive synthesis using arbitrary sine waves with inverse rectangular FFTs.

This requires two things:

1. The ability to generate phase/amplitude lists that cause the IFFT to create sine waves that are not integer multiples of 1/(IFFT length)

Example:  How do I generate 1000 Hz with 16 sample IFFTs at 44100 Hz?

2. The ability combine two frames pre-IFFT so they are added post-fft.

What are the necessary steps here?

Comment: This can be done but it's tedious and inefficient. There are some extremely efficient oscillator algorithms that work in the time domain. What's wrong with using those ?

Comment: I'm working in wavetable synthesis and I'm sort of assuming that if I pile up enough oscilators in the fft domain it'll outperform a typical additive synth.   Note:  The oscillators here would be of stable frequency but not amplitude.

Comment: what is the connection you have between [wavetable synthesis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228992574_Wavetable_Synthesis_101_A_Fundamental_Perspective) and [sinusoidal modeling with the STFT](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3927319_Intraframe_time-scaling_of_nonstationary_sinusoids_within_the_phase_vocoder)? i don't see them as directly related to each other.

Comment: My first choice would be to use a simple NCO (Numerically Controlled Oscillator) to generate any arbitrary sinewave with extremely high precision, fidelity, ability for nearly instantaneous frequency change and minimum resources. Have you ruled this out? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37803/numerically-controlled-oscillator-nco-for-phasor-implementation/37804#37804

Answer (score 1):

The FFT of a non-integer multiple frequency is very complex, you don't want to go there!

There are various oscillator schemes that are a few MAC instructions per sample such as https://vicanek.de/articles/QuadOsc.pdf
Checkout a review here: https://www.njohnson.co.uk/pdf/drdes/Chap7.pdf