Gaussian Pulse shaping filter
I need expert advice on implementation of Gaussian Pulse Shaping filter for generating GMSK signal in further steps. I have implemented as follows, Can anyone confirm that the Pulse would be shaped as desired by the Gaussian Pulse Shaping filter. The output is triangular not desired. I have used 256 bipolar values with BT=0.4, sample rate= 2 MSPS, data rate=9600 bps. I was not able to find implementation in C/ C++. Can anyone provide me the correct source code. I don't want to use any library. Thanks
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846

// Function to calculate the Gaussian pulse shaping filter coefficients
void gaussian_filter_coefficients(double *coeffs, int num_coeffs, double bt, double sps) {
    double alpha = sqrt(log(2) / 2.0) / bt;
    double scale_factor = sqrt(log(2) / PI) / alpha;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < num_coeffs; i++) {
        double t = (i - (num_coeffs - 1) / 2.0) / sps;
        coeffs[i] = scale_factor * exp(-2.0 * PI * PI * alpha * alpha * t * t);
    }
}

// Function to apply the filter to a signal
void apply_filter(const double *input, double *output, const double *coeffs, int input_len, int num_coeffs) {
    int half_num_coeffs = num_coeffs / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < input_len; i++) {
        output[i] = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < num_coeffs; j++) {
            int k = i - j + half_num_coeffs;
            if (k >= 0 && k < input_len) {
                output[i] += coeffs[j] * input[k];
            }
        }
    }
}


I won't provide the CC++ implementation, but hopefully the following details in Python can be used for validation and direction for the approach to use.
GMSK is implemented as data given as rectangular pulses filtered with a Gaussian filter. The output of the Gaussian filter is proportional to frequency versus time, so can then be scaled and used as the frequency control word input into a numerically controlled oscillator (NCO) to produce a GMSK waveform prior to up-conversion to a particular carrier frequency.

The duration (or memory) of the Gaussian filter is the inverse of the bandwidth-time product (BT). When BT=1, the filter concludes it's impulse response for every symbol just prior to the start of the next symbol, and thus there is no overlap between symbols. This is referred to as "Full-Response Signaling". When BT<1, the impulse response from one symbol overlaps into the subsequent symbols, and thus there is an intentional inter-symbol-interference (ISI) resulting in greater spectral efficiency at the expense of receiver complexity. For the OP's case, BT=0.4, and the impulse response for each symbol lasts for 2.5 symbols.
Below is my simulation for comparison of the expected result using the OP's design parameters:
BT = 0.4     Bandwidth-Time Product
f_s = 2 MHz  Sampling Rate 
R = 9600     Data Rate
Example Data Pattern:

I used the following code in Python to generate the filter.
def gpulse(ts, bt, fs):
    '''
    Returns coefficients for gaussian pulse filter
    ts: symbol period
    bt: bandwidth-time product
    fs: sampling rate
    
    GMSK is implemented with data as rectangular pulses into filter
    with output of filter representing frequency vs time
    (as input to NCO or VCO after scaling based on NCO/VCO used)

    Dan Boschen 5/26/2024
    '''
    sigma = np.sqrt(np.log(2))/(2*np.pi*bt)
    t = np.arange( int(ts * fs / bt) ) / fs - ts/(2 * bt)
    h = 1 / (np.sqrt(2*np.pi) * sigma * ts) * np.exp(-t**2 / (2 * sigma**2 * ts**2))
    return  h / fs  # scaled for 0 dB gain

The plot below is the Gaussian filter coefficients when using the OP's parameters:

Importantly note that given the OP's sample rate and data rate, the duration of the above filter is exactly 2.5 symbols (inverse of the bandwidth-time product).
The resulting output of the filter with the test sequence used is plotted below. Note the waveform into the filter consists of rectangular pulses mapped to +1 or -1, and the filter has been normalized for 0 dB gain.  The scaling of the filter output corresponding to the frequency of the transmitted carrier is $R/4$ where $R$ is the data rate. We also see the effect of the expected filter delay in the resulting filter output.

The Python code used to generate the filtered data is below:
bt = .4
fs = 2e6
data_rate = 9600
ts = 1/data_rate                          # symbol period (seconds)
t = np.arange(nsyms * Ts * fs)/fs - nsyms * Ts/2
rect = np.ones(int(fs * Ts))
data = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1])
symbol = np.ones( (int(fs/data_rate),len(data)) )
pulses = (symbol*data).T.flatten()

coeff = gpulse(ts, bt, fs)
filtered_data = sig.lfilter(coeff,1, pulses)


Thanks alot for thevery informative reply. Actually i have read that GMSK generation with I Q method is most accurate as VCO method introduces inaccuracy etc. So i did integration also but somehow the results are not achieved. Can you give me any hint or code on how to implement I Q way with Gausin filter, Accumulator (integrator) and I Q generation.  Might be my code has some mistakes. Thanks once again.

I am not suggesting an analog VCO method but a digital NCO. With that you can get any accuracy you desire based on how many bits you use in the NCO.  Overall this is much simpler than the IQ method (NCO has no multipliers, you can drive the input directly from the scaled filter output, the required overlap for partial response signaling is accounted for directly in the filter so no subsequent integration required as the NCO is the necessary integerator).

I provide more details on how to implement an NCO here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/37804/21048   Using that as I describe would be my recommended approach for making a GMSK modulator with BT<1.  But did I answer your question here as posted which was how to implement a Gaussian filter?

Thanks again for providing guidance. My aim is to use sdr for GMSK. As per my knowledge IQ samples need to be sent to SDR. So if I go with the NCO method than would I need to convert NCO output to IQ samples for SDR

Yes, in that case use a complex NCO (with Sine and Cosine output) to generate the baseband GMSK waveform. So you would effectively be creating a positive frequency to shift up and a negative frequency to shift down. The complex NCO output would be the IQ samples.

Thanks. For filter you provided coefficient generation code. Can you provide code to apply filter to bipolar samples because it's the one I am stuck at as shown in my plots.

The output of the filter is the convolution of the rectangular waveform with the filter coefficients. See here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution and if that doesn’t clear it up please post it as a new question detailing your attempt at convolution and what you are stuck on
