# How to implement a digital sawtooth oscillator?

Tags: phase, oscillator

In reference to this topic: [How to implement a digital oscillator?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/124/how-to-implement-a-digital-oscillator), I would like to know how can I implement a solution similar to the one in the topic on a Sawtooth oscillator.

Comment: What specific difficulty are you facing? Implement in software, hardware, firmware? What are your requirements (distortion, frequency, etc)?

Comment: Welcome to SP.SE!  As MBaz says, your question is way too broad. Please [edit it](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/40748/edit) and add some of the specifics he asks for and any other information you have (like why the approach you took doesn't work).

Answer (score 2):

Refer to think link, and use the truncated phase word directly (no look-up-table needed):

[Numerically Controlled Oscillator (NCO) for phasor implementation?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37803/numerically-controlled-oscillator-nco-for-phasor-implementation/37804#37804)